# minimumDate and maximumDate of UIDatePicker cannot be set in code?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

In my NIB file, I have a UIDatePicker. I connect it to a IBOutlet property.
In the - (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder method in my Controller, I set the minimumDate and maximumDate like this:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; 
        NSDate *beginDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2010-01-01"];  
        NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2010-12-31"]; 
        picker.minimumDate = beginDate;
        picker.maximumDate = endDate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

But when the app is running, there is no change about my UIDatePicker.
Did I have some mistakes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your picker binding is not done in the `initWithCoder` method, as the XIB file is not loaded at this stage.

Place you code in `awakeFromNib`

```
- ( void )awakeFromNib
{
   ...
}
```

And by the way, you forgot to release your `NSDateFormatter` object...